# local pointer may point to deallocated memory

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, clion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int wordLen(char *c_str) {
    int len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; c_str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        len++;
    }
    printf("%s has a total of %d characters!\n", c_str, len);
    return len;
}

char *allocWord(char *c_str) {
    int size_needed = wordLen(c_str) + 1;
    char *heap_str = malloc(sizeof(char) * size_needed);

    heap_str[(size_needed - 1)] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < (size_needed - 1); i++) {
        heap_str[i] = c_str[i];
    }
    printf("Allocated space for the word %s!", heap_str);
    return heap_str;
}

char *reverseWord(char *src_str) {
    char *reverse = allocWord(src_str);
    int str_len = wordLen(reverse);

    int right = str_len - 1;

    for (int left = 0; left < right; left++) {
        char tmp = reverse[left];
        reverse[left] = reverse[right];
        reverse[right] = tmp;
        right--;
    }
    printf("The reverse of %s, is %s\n", src_str, reverse);
    return reverse;
}

void wordCompare(char *first_str, char *second_str) {
    int len = wordLen(first_str);
    if (len != wordLen(second_str)) {
        printf("Word lengths don't match!\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (first_str[i] != second_str[i]) {
            printf("Strings don't match starting from the character %d which is %c\n",
                   i + 1, first_str[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Strings are identical\n");
}

int main() {
    char *str1 = allocWord("Palindrome");
    char *reverse = reverseWord(str1);

    char *str2 = allocWord("racecar");
    char *reverse2 = reverseWord(str2);

    wordCompare(str1, reverse);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    wordCompare(str2, reverse2);

    free(str2);
    free(reverse2);
    printf("HERE: %s\n", reverse);
    free(str1);
    free(reverse);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code is pretty simple, I mimic the `strlen` function to find the word lengths, and have another function that allocates some memory for a string and returns the pointer on the heap.

Then I have a function that reverses a string and one that mimics `strcmp` to check if the word itself and the reverse is the same. The code works fine.

The problem is my IDE warns me that after I deallocate the `reverse2` variable it might mean that the `reverse` variable is also unreachable. I do not understand why this would be the case cause I call the method separately for each of them and save them in different variables.

The problem `Local variable 'reverse' may point to deallocated memory`  shows at line 75 which is `printf("HERE: %s\n", reverse);`

Comment: I don't see any problems with this code. IMHO the warning is wrong (and pointless).

Comment: Thanks! It was confusing me since the code was very straightforward.

Comment: This gives no warning in GCC. What compiler / settings are you using?

Comment: I use Clion to compile and run, I see the warning in the IDE.

Comment: [Bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-21666/Wrong-warning-Local-variable-data-may-point-to-deallocated-memory) & [Bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-25277/Bogus-local-variable-may-point-to-deallocate-memory-warning) seems to suggest CLion has a problem. When you check this out on the CLion bug tracker you would see a lot of these type of issues.

Comment: What's with the custom `wordLen()` and `wordCompare()` - what's wrong with `strlen()` and `strncmp()` from `<string.h>`?

Comment: If you move the `printf()` before the other two `free()` statements, does the violation go away?  But I agree with the others, that this looks like a false report.

Comment: @Andrew there is no problem with them, I was just practicing for an exam and we cannot use stringh in exams.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in the code, but none that should produce the warning `Local variable 'reverse' may point to deallocated memory`.  Is it possible that you might be compiling an older version of the program?

Nonetheless, you should fix these:

- the header file `<malloc.h>` is non standard. Use `<stdlib.h>` instead.
- the string arguments for `wordLen`, `allocWord` and `wordCompare` should be defined as `const char *` to document that these strings are not modified by the functions and to allow passing string literals without warnings at stricter warning levels.
- you might want to use `size_t` for the string lengths and test for potential memory allocation failures.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t wordLen(const char *c_str) {
    size_t len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; c_str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        len++;
    }
    printf("%s has a total of %zu characters!\n", c_str, len);
    return len;
}

char *allocWord(const char *c_str) {
    size_t len = wordLen(c_str);
    char *heap_str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

    if (heap_str == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %s\n", c_str);
        exit(1);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        heap_str[i] = c_str[i];
    }
    heap_str[len] = '\0';

    printf("Allocated space for the word %s\n", heap_str);
    return heap_str;
}

char *reverseWord(const char *src_str) {
    char *reverse = allocWord(src_str);
    size_t str_len = wordLen(reverse);
    size_t right = str_len;

    for (size_t left = 0; left < right; left++) {
        char tmp = reverse[left];
        reverse[left] = reverse[--right];
        reverse[right] = tmp;
    }
    printf("The reverse of %s is %s\n", src_str, reverse);
    return reverse;
}

int wordCompare(const char *first_str, const char *second_str) {
    size_t len = wordLen(first_str);
    if (len != wordLen(second_str)) {
        printf("Word lengths don't match!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (first_str[i] != second_str[i]) {
            printf("Strings don't match starting from the character %zu which is %c <-> %c\n",
                   i + 1, first_str[i], second_str[i]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Strings are identical\n");
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char *str1 = allocWord("Palindrome");
    char *reverse1 = reverseWord(str1);
    char *str2 = allocWord("racecar");
    char *reverse2 = reverseWord(str2);

    wordCompare(str1, reverse1);
    wordCompare(str2, reverse2);

    free(str2);
    free(reverse2);
    printf("HERE: %s\n", reverse1);
    free(str1);
    free(reverse1);

    return 0;
}
```